# How to delete part of a character value column of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
  [1] NA                         NA                         
  [3] NA                         NA                         
  [5] "kilo130.9"            "kilo5075.69"       
  [7] "kilo465"              "kilo34.8"            
  [9] "kilo607.195"          "kilo1362.7"
```

Above is the column of a dataframe that I have copy pasted from R
I ran the code below to delete the word kilo from the column but it does not work. I don't get an error but it does not delete the word kilo. I used the code below

```
stopwords = readLines('stopwords.txt') #I put the word kilo in this txt file
x  = df$Dist
x  =  removeWords(x,stopwords)
df$newdist<-x
```

What could be the reson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeWords()` is only going to remove words that exactly match `"kilo"` (with no other characters):

```
x <- c("kilo", "kilo2", "pound")
tm::removeWords(x, "kilo")
#> [1] ""      "kilo2" "pound"
```

Here's another option:

```
library("stringr")
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "kilo130.9", "kilo5075.69", "kilo465", "kilo34.8", "kilo607.195", "kilo1362.7")
str_replace(x, "kilo", "")
#>  [1] NA        NA        NA        NA        "130.9"   "5075.69" "465"    
#>  [8] "34.8"    "607.195" "1362.7"
```

Comment: The second option worked. But the first option did not work for me. DO I have to run some library for the first option to work?

Comment: Sorry the first was just to clarify that `removeWords()` will only work on exact matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `gsub`:

```
# Sample data
w <- c(
    NA, NA,
    NA, NA,
    "kilo130.9", "kilo5075.69",
    "kilo465", "kilo34.8",
    "kilo607.195", "kilo1362.7")

# Strings that should be deleted
stopwords <- c("kilo", "something");

sapply(w, function(x)
    x <- gsub(sprintf("(%s)", paste(stopwords, collapse = "|")), "", x));
#       <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>   kilo130.9 kilo5075.69
#         NA          NA          NA          NA     "130.9"   "5075.69"
#    kilo465    kilo34.8 kilo607.195  kilo1362.7
#      "465"      "34.8"   "607.195"    "1362.7"
```

Comment: sapply(w, function(x)
    x <- gsub(sprintf("(%s)", paste(stopwords, collapse = "|")), "", x));               This line is executing but is not removing kilo! Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Alli what do you mean? It’s working just fine, as per my example code and output. Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Alli Are you perhaps confused about how to store the result? You can do e.g. `res <- sapply(w, ...)`.

Comment: I typed the line below as one single line in R and ran your same program by copy pasting into R but it is not removing the string                                                                   sapply(y, function(x) gsub(sprintf("(%s)", paste(stopwords, collapse = "|")), "", x));  The result of w after running the program is                    w
 [1] NA            NA            NA            NA           
 [5] "kilo130.9"   "kilo5075.69" "kilo465"     "kilo34.8"   
 [9] "kilo607.195" "kilo1362.7"

Comment: @Alli Did you *save* the output? Above lines only prints the output to demonstrate. If you do `res <- sapply(w, ....)`, then `res` is the `character` vector with entries from which `"kilo"` has been removed.